# Setting Gradle dependencies from zip file

Tags: gradle, compilation, zip

I am very new to gradle and looking for the solution to the following problem.

I have a zip (xy.zip) file which has few jar files in the following folder:
./abc/x.jar
./abc/y.jar

This zip file is in local artifactory with following pom details:

```
group = "com.xy", name="xy-name", version = "1.1.0"
```

Now, I am trying to set the dependency as

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.xy', name: 'xy-name', version: '1.1.0', ext: 'zip')
}
```

This dependency downloads the zip from the artifactory but I'm unable to get x.jar and y.jar on the compiled location.

I think this is not the correct way. Can someone please help in setting the above jars during compile time?

Comment: Unfortunately I think it won't work that way. The zip file will be downloaded but it needs further processing. You should download the zip file first, unzip it, then add unzipped directory to dependencies tree.

Comment: Did you get this working? I am trying a similar approach and the gradle does not respect the version number of the zip file

Comment: Any luck with this?